# WP Super Cache How to use the plugin with an SSL connection

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

My site is in SSL mode, but the plugin didn't seem to work when I first installed it several days ago. And then I tried the cache test, I received the following error message:

```
arning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /var/www/html/abc.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 1008

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/html/abc.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 1008

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://www.abc.com:443 (Unknown error) in /var/www/html/abc.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 1008
```

find /class-http.php on line 1008

```
$handle = stream_socket_client( $connect_host . ':' . $arrURL['port'], $connection_error, $connection_error_str, $connect_timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context );
```

So how can I use the plugin without disabling SSL?

THX